# What is React Native method of getting user’s input like React’s e.target.innerText

Tags: reactjs, react-native

‪please what  is React Native’s replacement of React’s e.target.innerText? I’m trying to get what a user click on from TouchableOpacity component  ‬

Comment: Somebody should please answer 

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a user’s choice with onPress props in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55346511/how-to-get-a-user-s-choice-with-onpress-props-in-react-native)